# "simple" perl assignment with .txt file

Tags: perl

I have an assignment that explains the following:

Write a small Perl program called names.pl reads in a list of first and last names (full name per line) and stores the names in two hashes (%firstNameHash and %lastNameHash). Below is the user interface showing how it should work. Hint, in Perl you can assign 2 variables at once: ($first, $last) = split / /, $line;

```
File name to read in: myFile.txt
(F) for first name (L) for last name search and (.) to exit: F
Enter first name: Mike
Jonas
(F) for first name (L) for last name search and (.) to exit: L
Enter last name: Jonas
Mike
(F) for first name (L) for last name search and (.) to exit: .
Done!
```

I find this explanation to be pretty confusing, but I get the interface. I have the test file (myFile.txt) we were assigned, and it looks like this:

```
Mike Jonas
Mark Jones
Max Tedford
Robbie MacPheson
Alison Bailey
```

I've watched some videos/read some articles for a couple hours, but when you don't know exactly what to look for, it can be confusing.

Could anyone suggest a possible direction to start in? It would really help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cross-posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/ec0xs0/very_confused_on_how_to_approach_beginner_perl/

Comment: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why you're watching videos and reading articles. Isn't this stuff in your course notes?

Answer (score 1):

[`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) can be used to open a file. [`<$fh>`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html) will read a line from the file whose handle is in `$fh`. [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) can be used to remove the trailing line feed from a variable's value

As for storing the names in two hashes... That doesn't make much sense. Hashes allows one to store values indexed by a string called a key. Should the name be used as a key or value of the hash element? If it's the key, what should be used as the value, and vice-versa. I can't help you with that.

By the way, you should always start your programs with `use strict; use warnings;`.

`($first, $last)` should be `my ($first, $last)`.

`split / /, $line` (splitting on each space) should be `split ' ', $line` (splitting on whitespace).